# How to separate business logic from Rx

Tags: typescript, reactivex, clean-architecture

I want to apply [Uncle Bob's clean architecture](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html). It restricts the application core -- entities and business logics -- to be agnostic about outside world, especially specific framework choices.

I understand, in theory at least, how to separate UI frameworks, DBAs, etc. However, I want to use Rx as my asynchronous solution and am wondering if I could separate it as well.

Suppse that I'm writing a client side authentication cache and it is resposible for providing login certificate, if any exists in the cache, and fetch it from the server, if required. Then I need a `IServer` interface (only interface, concrete implementation will be a 'outer layer' concern):

```
interface IServer {
    getCertificate(phone: string, password: string): Observable
}
```

Can I somehow inverse this dependecy on `Observable`?

The workaround I can think out for now is to use plain old callback style

```
interface IServer {
    getCertificate(phone: string, password: string, callback: () => Void)
}
```

Is this the only way?

Or

Shall I separate Rx from my logic in the first place?

---

A second thought: Are there any abstract interface/protocol standard to include into my project? (p.s. I'm using typescript)

Then the problem becomes: my business logic depends on an abstract ReactiveX interface definition and I may go with that. I can regard it as a fundamental choice I have to make in the early phase, like the programming language choice.

Comment: @VadimKotov I added it, but I suppose this is somewhat a universal design problem than a language-specific one

Comment: @NandiinBao yes and no. Rx is meant to handle *event streams*, not asynchronous calls. It's used for async calls in languages that *don't* have explicit support for async calls, eg the `await` keyword. BTW Typescript *does* have `async/await`. The thing with asynchronous calls though is that unless they bubble all the way to the top they *aren't* asynchronous.

Comment: @NandiinBao If you care about how a call is made, it's a very, very strong indication that you *aren't* dealing with business logic. In this case `Server` isn't a business entity even if you are creating a certificate management web site. It's an *interface* to a remote service.

Comment: @NandiinBao using the callback style is dirty. The method is *still* calling a remote service, it will run asynchronously, but the way it exposes this to clients doesn't make this clear.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand that `Server` isn't a business entity. I may left it unclear: I'm writing a client side authentication cache, which calls `getCertificate` for login and then caches the certificate for further usage. `Server` is the interface it demands from outer layer. I suppose this authentication cache is definitely a business logic and it's up to this cache to decide how the `Server` interface should look like.

Answer (score 0):

In clean architecture the actual threading and caching implementation are details which should be kept away from business logic and instead e.g. kept in gateways.

That said Observables are just like promises, used to abstract threading away. If Observable interfaces and classes come from ur language standard library like in .Net using them in your business logic is probably not so much an issue. On the other hand if these interfaces and classes come from third party libraries you should be careful and may want to consider abstracting these away e.g. using adapter and factory patterns to keep ur business logic clean.

**Update:** For a more detailed discussion on "how to integrate frameworks in Clean Architecture" pls refer to my blog post http://www.plainionist.net/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-Frameworks/